# Getting an error when trying to sign in with the correct information

Tags: php, swift, xcode

I am trying to make a login system for my app. whenever I run my app and type in the correct email and password, I get this error `iHertz[2889:191536] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_NSZeroData)'` I don't know if this has to do with my php file or my swift file. ALSO Im getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT once I press loginbutton.

Code from my .swift file

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "not a string")
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Data(), options: .fragmentsAllowed ) as? NSDictionary //CAUTION: Cast from 'Data' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails
        if let parseJSON = json {
            let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String
            if (id?.isEmpty)! {
                return
            }                    
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = tabBarController
            }
        } else {

        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Code form my userLogin.php file

```
require("iHertzmusic.ini");
require("access.php");
$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secured_password = sha1($password); 
$dao = new access(); 
$dao->connect();
$userDetails = $dao->selectUser($email,$secured_password);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";

echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {

$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is not found";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
}

$dao->disconnect();
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated, if been trying for days.

Comment: Not related to your question but you should chenge `(Data, URLResponse, Error) in`  to `data, response, error in`, change `if Error != nil {` to `guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }` and then print the json string from your `data`. print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "not a string"` then edit your question and add it to your post

Comment: I added it, @LeoDabus I don't think I did its right... It gave me like 15 errors

Comment: remove those two lines after the print statement `return` and 
        `}` check my edit

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok I added it. Im having trouble with my 'display message' and 'task.resume()'

Comment: please edit your question and show your json print string result

Comment: make sure your task.resume() is called after the closing bracket

Comment: make sure to balance your brackets properly. looks like you have added the closing bracket that I told you to remove back to your code. check my last edit again

Comment: @LeoDabus I edited my post. I am getting a caution error saying Cast from 'Data' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails. This result in a app delegate Thread 1: signal SIGABRT once I press loginbutton

Comment: you have added again a closing bracket where you shouldn't. Regarding your comment you should use the `data` instance `Data()` would create a new empty data object. And do not try to cast it to NSDictionary.  Forget about `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject` You should use JSONDecoder. Try googling about Codable protocol

Comment: check my last edit. Again please add your json result to your post otherwise I can't help you parsing it.

Comment: Have you validated that the json produced by the server is correct?